# willHideViewController called despite the app is in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm developing an iPad app that launches in landscape mode.

The first screen displays a UISplitViewController and my issue is that altough the app is in landscape mode the delegate is notified on `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` despite that the documentation states that:

> When the split view controller rotates
>   from a landscape to portrait
>   orientation, it normally hides one of
>   its view controllers. When that
>   happens, it calls this method to
>   coordinate the addition of a button to
>   the toolbar (or navigation bar) of the
>   remaining custom view controller. If
>   you want the soon-to-be hidden view
>   controller to be displayed in a
>   popover, you must implement this
>   method and use it to add the specified
>   button to your interface.

As the app is in landscape mode and not transitioning to portrait I don't get why my delegate is notified. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0):

valentin, to directly answer "why is it so?", i think the answer is simply that it's a bug in the implementation of their API.

as you seem to have found, when in landscape orientation, it calls the above when it sort of seems that it shouldn't, and then calls splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem: .

also, i discovered that when in portrait orientation, it sends a very early message (i.e. before the view.frame has been adjusted) to `splitViewController:willHideViewController:withBarButtonItem:forPopoverController:` .

the one thing i saw that annoyed me the most was that, using the code provided from their template creation, the button bar would appear and then disappear at startup.

my solution was to implement a workaround, which i have posted on git@github.com:johnkdoe/freeforall.git in the class KludgeWorkaroundForBuggySplitViewDelegateStartup .

make this a superclass of your current detail view controller class, as in

```
//@interface MyViewController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
@interface MyViewController : KludgeWorkaroundForBuggySplitViewDelegateStartup
```

this will set the initial button bar title to Master if you don't have something you prefer.  you can override this by overriding the @property getter in your subclass implementation.  if you want to do more than what's in this kludgeWorkaround class, you can override these yourself and (either copy and paste or) call [super ...] on them prior to doing your own work.

i can't say this solves the problem of what appears to me to be an implementation bug, but the workaround gets rid of the brief appearance of the button bar at startup of a split-view-controller app in landscape mode.